# Why does changing the number of protons cause such a fundamental change in an element?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, protons, elements

When we change the number of electrons in an atom of an element, it constitutes an ion. When we change the number of neutrons of an element it constitutes an isotope. But when we change the number of protons of an element, the change is so drastic that it constitutes a whole new element.  Why is it so?